# How to prevent spaces and full stops in input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, field

I have the following to disallow spaces

```
function nospaces(t){

    if(t.value.match(/\s/g)){

        alert('Username Cannot Have Spaces or Full Stops');

        t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');

    }

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
```

It works well for spaces but how can I also disallow full stops as well?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    function nospaces(t){
        if(t.value.match(/\s|\./g)){
            alert('Username Cannot Have Spaces or Full Stops');
            t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. I just changed the last line to t.value=t.value.replace(/\s|\./g,'');

Comment: I tried but not snough reputation. Once I get a good rep I will come back and vote up

Comment: oh forgot abt that. I have been there once :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample html and javscript you just wanted to add /./g for checking for .

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
<script>
function nospaces(t){

    if( t.value.match(/\s/g) || t.value.match(/\./g)  ){

        alert('Username Cannot Have Spaces or Full Stops');

        t.value= (t.value.replace(/\s/g,'') .replace(/\./g,''));

    }

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If not its not necessary to use **regex** you can use

```
if(value.indexOf('.') != -1) {
    alert("dots not allowed");
}
```

or if required

```
if(value.match(/\./g) != null) {
    alert("Dots not allowed");
}
```