# Not allowing to write spaces in input using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for a lot of functions that let me block the user from writing spaces on my input BUT I can't seem anyone that actually works with me.. Maybe I'm not just doing it the right way and I'd appreciate a little help.

This is my HTML form:

```
<table>
<form name="form_registar" method="post" action="registado.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nome de Utilizador" id="textboxEmail" maxlength="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password" id="textbox" maxlength="15">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="cpw" placeholder="Confirmar Password" id="textbox" maxlength="15">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" id="textbox" onkeypress="return isLetter(event)" maxlength="15">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="apelido" placeholder="Apelido" id="textbox" onkeypress="return isLetter(event)" maxlength="15">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="textboxEmail" maxlength="50">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Data de Nascimento:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" name="dataNasc" id="textbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Masculino<input type="radio" name="sex" value="M" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        Feminino<input type="radio" name="sex" value="F">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="submit-button"><b>Registar</b></button>
      </td>
  </form>
  <form action="index.html">
  <td>
  <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Cancelar</button>
  </td>
  </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to block the user to write spaces in one or more input fields. I can't sem to know how.

EDIT: isLetter and isNumber are functions to only allow the user to write letters and numbers respectively.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
This is my javascript functions, I'm looking for one that blocks the user from writing spaces:

```
/* APENAS PERMITE NUMEROS */
 function isNumber(evt) {
         evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
     /* APENAS PERMITE LETRAS */
 function isLetter(evt) {
         evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
         var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
             ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
             (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
     /* VALIDAR O FORM */
 $(function chora() {
     $('#user').on('keypress', function chora(e) {
         if (e.which == 32)
             return false;
     });
 });

 function validateForm() {
     /* USERNAME */
     var a = document.forms["form_registar"]["user"].value;
     if (a == null || a == "") {
         alert("O Username não está preenchido.");
         return false;
     }
     /* PASSWORD */
     var b = document.forms["form_registar"]["pw"].value;
     if (b == null || b == "") {
         alert("A password não está preenchida.");
         return false;
     }
     /* CONFIRMAR PASSWORD */
     var c = document.forms["form_registar"]["cpw"].value;
     if (c == null || c == "") {
         alert("A confirmação de password não está preenchida.");
         return false;
     }
     /* NOME */
     var d = document.forms["form_registar"]["nome"].value;
     if (d == null || d == "") {
         alert("O nome não está preenchido.");
         return false;
     }
     /* APELIDO */
     var e = document.forms["form_registar"]["apelido"].value;
     if (e == null || e == "") {
         alert("O apelido não está preenchido.");
         return false;
     }
     /* EMAIL */
     var f = document.forms["form_registar"]["email"].value;
     var atpos = f.indexOf("@");
     var dotpos = f.lastIndexOf(".");
     if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= f.length) {
         alert("O E-mail não se encontra devidamente preenchido.");
         return false;
     }
     /* DATANASC */
     var g = document.forms["form_registar"]["dataNasc"].value;
     if (g == null || g == "") {
         alert("A Data de Nascimento não está preenchida.");
         return false;
     }
     /* CONFIRMAÇAO PW*/
     var h = document.forms["form_registar"]["pw"].value;
     var i = document.forms["form_registar"]["cpw"].value;
     if (h != i) {
         alert("As passwords não correspondem.");
         return false;
     }

 }
```

Comment: look up regular expression and make use of them to check that no input data contains space.

Comment: I suggest you listen to keydown or change event on all input fields and clear the contents in case those fail validations

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent spaces and full stops in input field with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756559/how-to-prevent-spaces-and-full-stops-in-input-field-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at jQuery.
Then you can use this:

```
$('#textbox').on('keydown',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var value = $this.val();
  $this.val(value.replace(/\s+/g,'')); // remove all whitespace characters
});
```

Also, you have multiple elements with id "textbox". Each id should be unique.

Comment: IDs should really be unique in a document. You can use css classes to achieve the same formatting: <input class="textbox"/>

Answer (score 1):

I have made a Jsfiddle for the same. Have a look here.

I have used 'keyCode' and 'which' function.
This will work on browsers and IOS ipad and iphone but not on Android Phones. They dont register 'KeyCode' or 'which' or 'keyChar'

```
var keycode;
$('.nospace').keypress(function (event) {
   keycode = (event.charCode) ? event.charCode : ((event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode);
   if (keycode == 32) {
    return false
  };
});
```

Check the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/P5Kjr/4/

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress` is too late. Try `onkeydown`.

Comment: This looks like a comment. Try to extend your answer with more explanation or examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the users to use the spacebar by checking if its pressed and then returning `false` like this:

```
​$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});​​​​​
```

[Take a look at this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/USJws/)

Comment: And where do I write that? How do I "call" the function to the form?

Comment: @White8Tiger Just add it to your javascript code? [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/USJws/161/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJFbt/45/)

***jQuery Code***

```
$("input").on({
    keydown: function (e) {
        if (e.which === 32) return false;
    },
    change: function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236954/2260614)